# What of Han Solo's pre-ANH past was revealed as canon prior to the release of Solo?

Tags: star-wars, canon, han-solo

Before *Solo* is released, how much of Han Solo's past before meeting Luke and Obi-Wan in Mos Eisley is canon? There are some pieces that are mentioned in *The Empire Strikes Back* and *Return Of The Jedi*, but how much was Legendified and hasn't been re-canonized? For instance:

- We know he won the Millennium Falcon from Lando. But do we know it was a game of Sabacc?
- Do we know how he and Chewy met? Is the "life debt" even canon, or is their exact relationship a mystery?
- We know Han dumped some cargo of Jabba's, do we know what it was? Is Spice canon?
- *The Force Awakens* made it sound like the "parsecs" part of the Kessel Run wasn't just Han trying to use space words to impress a farm boy. Is the navigating-hyperspace retcon canon?

Comment: The first 3 questions are answered in the novels that came out in the 80's, but I don't think they have been deemed canon.

Comment: Why are people still hung up on the definition of _parsec_? It was a bad translation in the original documentary, that's all it was. It makes perfect sense if you read it in the original Klingon. ;)

Comment: Wookiepedia deems the Del Rey novels as a "resource" - "All novels, junior novels, reference books, sourcebooks, and other books published prior to the Lucasfilm declaration of April 25, 2014"

Comment: The life debt is canon - it's even the name of the second canon "Aftermath" book in which Han and Chewie play a role

Comment: Spice is canon--C-3PO mentions "the spice mines of Kessel" in ANH--but I don't know if that was Han's cargo for Jabba in canon.

Comment: I think the answer to these questions will be revealed in about 4 months

Comment: @psubsee2003 This question specifically asks what's canon NOW. Before Solo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Legends, Solo was born on Corellia, [which seems to be the case in the new canon as well.](http://www.starwars.com/databank/han-solo)

[image]

> **LOCATIONS:** Mos Eisley Spaceport, Corellia

The Sabacc game is also still canon, according to *Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know*.

[image]

> Han didn't buy the *Millennium Falcon*. He won the ship from Lando Calrissian, who bet the *Falcon* in a high-stakes game of Sabacc!

[As is the spice backstory.](http://www.starwars.com/databank/jabba-the-hutt-biography-gallery)

[image]

> After smuggler Han Solo jettisoned a shipment of Jabba's spice before being boarded by an Imperial patrol, Jabba demanded compensation...

And Wookiee [life debts](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Life_debt) are still canon, [including Chewbacca's](http://www.starwars.com/news/6-of-the-best-friendships-in-star-wars).

[image]

> Han Solo and Chewbacca have an unbreakable bond. Their friendship started because of a Wookiee life debt, but I believe Chewbacca would stay by Han’s side even without that obligation hanging over his furry head.

Comment: You might want to mention that the dice seen in The Last Jedi are established to be the "chance cubes" he used to win the Falcon

Comment: Nicely done. Can you make the source of all of these screenshots clearer? Do they all come from _Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know_, or just the first one?

Comment: @Plutor The sources are all linked in the statements. The other screenshots come from the official Star Wars website.